# jQuery Each Function Inside a jQuery Each Function

Tags: jquery, each

I can't figure out if this is possible, basically want to run an each function on every article and run another each function inside that each function on every li in that article, is this possible? I can post more details later.

Comment: Yes. Post more details.

Comment: hell yeah!! its possible.. why do you think that is not possible..

Comment: When posting here, don't expect people to wait for _"more details later"_.  Put some effort into making the post as good as possible on your _first_ attempt, and please don't ask for something that you can easily try out for yourself.

Comment: Hey Sparky, I did try things and searched around and that's why I posted, I couldn't find anything quickly. Sometimes documentation is difficult to understand without contexts, we aren't all trained programmers here, that's why we're here in the first place, to learn from example and to ask when we don't find. I feel like this question is unique enough to warrant the post, if I am wrong, then show me where this has been answered, because I couldn't find it, and don't say it's easy to figure out yourself, everyone is at different levels of understanding.

Answer (score 9):

The jQuery $.each() function is just a loop. It iterates through the item that the selector returns. Since this is the case, if you select every UL on the page, then while viewing that UL item, you select all li items for that UL, then so on and all spans in each li. You can go on forever if the items are there. It doesn't matter, it is just a loop.

```
 $.each("ul", function(index, element)
 {
      var $this = $(this);
      var $items = $this.find("li");
      //now next loop
      $.each($items, function(n, e)
      {
          //this is each li in this ul
      });
 });
```

Comment: What's the point of passing `index, element` if you're not going to use either of them?

Comment: Just displaying that you can use them incase the user was not aware of the function.

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
jQuery.each([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]], function(index, value) {
  jQuery.each(value, function(subindex, subvalue) {
    console.log(subvalue);
  });
});
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```